# Conversion of a dataframe column to list for dynamic UI generation in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to generate an `checkboxGroupInput` in a `Shiny` interface dynamically using the `renderUI` function.

`checkboxGroupInput` requires a `list` for the choices. I have extracted a column from a data frame which I would like to be presented as choices for the boxes, the column looks like (converted to list with `as.list()`)

```
 str(A)
List of 1
 $ B: num [1:4] 0 5 1 10
```

where I would like to convert `A` to something like

```
A <- list("0" = 0, "1" = 1, "5" = 5, "10" = 10)
```

i.e, named list in ascending order, so that I can feed it into `choices = A` in `checkboxGroupInput`.

I am not sure how to proceed with this at all, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I did wonder if you meant to extract with `[["B"]]` rather than `[1]` or `["B"]`since you got a list rather than a vector.) With this result you would first need to `unlist` since it is a one element list at the moment> and then use as.list and `setNames` on that result:

```
A <- list(B=c( 0, 5, 1, 10))
setNames( as.list( sort( unlist(A))), sort(A$B))
#----output----
$`0`
[1] 0

$`1`
[1] 1

$`5`
[1] 5

$`10`
[1] 10
```

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust, I converted to `list` because `options` requires a `list` in `checkboxGroupInput`. Would it be easier if `A` were a `vector` or a column of `dataframe` (still a `dataframe`)?

Comment: I was just wondering, not saying you had made an error. I now see that you wanted the elements sorted. Added code to do that.